# Iterator Confused

Tags: java, iterator, queue

I had some trouble with the whole iterator concept and for a question in one of my quizzes, I honestly couldn't understand what was up.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    Deque<String> SQ1 = new ArrayDeque<String>();

     SQ1.add("Give");
     SQ1.add("Me");
     SQ1.add("The");
     SQ1.add("Best");
     SQ1.add("Of");
     SQ1.add("Both");
     SQ1.add("Worlds");
     Iterator<String> It = SQ1.iterator();

     while(It.hasNext())
     {
         if(It.next().equals("Give"))
             System.out.print(It.next());
     }
}
```

This is the code, and the question is what will be the output. The correct answer is `"Me"` when I thought it was `"Give"`. I don't understand how the whole run goes.

This is what I understand:
It does have a `next`. If that `next` equals `"Give"`, it will print out that `next` value.   In this case, that value should be "Give", shouldn't it?

Could someone please help me understand this?

Comment: Inside the `if` it calls `next().equals("Give")` which catches it when it iterates to `"Give"`. Then when printing, it calls `next()` again, which iterates it to `"Me"`.

Comment: Thank you! That was one of the theories I had but I thought it didn't make sense. Thank you for clearing that out for me.

Comment: `Returns the next element in the iteration.` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Comment: Additionally, local variables do not begin with capital letters in the standard Java coding convention.

Answer (score 3):

The if-statement calls `It.next()` to check the value, and the the print statement calls `It.next()` **again**, rather than printing the value that you just checked.

So what you see will always be the element **directly after** `"Give"`.

Answer (score 2):

> The correct answer is "Me" when I thought it was "Give". I don't understand how the whole run goes.

Right, the code is illustrating a common error. The error is that the code is telling the iterator to advance to the next item and give it to us **twice**:

```
Iterator<String> It = SQ1.iterator();
while(It.hasNext())
{
    if(It.next().equals("Give"))
// here^^^^^^^^^
        System.out.print(It.next());
// and here -------------^^^^^^^^^
}
```

So it's getting the value, seeing if it's `"Give"`, and then if that value was `"Give"` it throws it away and gets the **next** value, which in your test data is `"Me"`. (Note that **if** `"Give"` were the last entry, that second call to `next` would throw an error, since there would be no next entry at that point.)

To "fix" it and have it show `"Give"`, still using that kind of loop, you'd remember the result of the call in a variable, and then use the variable in those two places:

```
Iterator<String> It = SQ1.iterator();
while(It.hasNext())
{
    String value = It.next();

    if(value.equals("Give"))
        System.out.print(value);
}
```

**But**, this is what the enhanced `for` loop is for: You don't use an `It` variable at all, just:

```
for (String value : SQ1) {
    if(value.equals("Give"))
        System.out.print(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you completely answered my next question. Great explanation thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the Java docs:

> next
>
> E next()
>   Returns the next element in the iteration.
>
> Returns:
>   the next element in the iteration
>
> Throws:
>   NoSuchElementException - if the iteration has no more elements

So your call:

```
If(It.next().equals("Give"))
```

Actually returns the "next" value and sets the Iterator 'It' to the next one in your ArrayDeque.
If you call next again you will be one step further.